# Can anyone please give me the correct justification , because i expected the anser to be 9 while the result was "0"?

Tags: python, function, loops, return, logic

```
def print_nums(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print(i)
        return 

print_nums(10)
```

With this code I was expecting the answer to be `9`, but I was really surprised to see `0` as the answer. Please could anyone provide the proper justification ?

Comment: `return` stops any further execution of your code, so the loop only runs once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your return is in the wrong spot

```
def print_nums(x):
for i in range(x):
    print(i)
return 

print_nums(10)
```

will print 0-9 on a new line every time, if you want to just print 9 you should do

```
def print_nums(x):
    for i in range(x):
    return i

print_nums(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_nums(x):
    for i in range(x): # Loop starts. In first iteration of loop, i = 0
        print(i)       # Prints 0, since i = 0
        return         # The function execution stops here and it exits

print_nums(10)
```

The above code will only run and stop on the first iteration of the loop. This is because return will directly exit from the function and so the function execution will stop there itself.

---

You probably intended to have the function in following way -

```
def print_nums(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print(i)
    return 

print_nums(10)
```

**Output :**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

You don't need return in the above case either if its not returning something that you are using.In either case, I don't understand how you are expecting the output to be 9. The above function will print all numbers from `0 to x-1`.

---

If you are looking to loop from `0 to x-1` and at last print x-1, then you can do it like this -

```
def print_nums(x):
    i = 0
    for i in range(x):
        # Some work done here
        pass
    print(i)     # Prints x-1 and returns from the function
    return 

print_nums(10)
```

**Output :**

```
9
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

it is because you call `return` inside the for loop. so the function return just after the first loop